# Confusion about Morte (calculus of constructions) typing

Tags: lambda-calculus, morte

In [Morte](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/morte-1.6.19) (an implementation of calculus of constructions) this expression is well typed:

```
$ morte
(  λ(Nat : *)
-> λ(Zero : Nat)
-> Zero
)
(∀(a : *) ->  (a ->  a) ->  a ->  a)
(λ(a : *) ->  λ(Succ : a ->  a) ->  λ(Zero : a) ->  Zero) 
^D
∀(a : *) → (a → a) → a → a

λ(a : *) → λ(Succ : a → a) → λ(Zero : a) → Zero
```

But this apparently equivalent expression is not:

```
$ morte
(  λ(Nat : *)
-> (  λ(Zero : Nat)
   -> Zero)
   (λ(a : *) ->  λ(Succ : a ->  a) ->  λ(Zero : a) ->  Zero)
)
(∀(a : *) ->  (a ->  a) ->  a ->  a)
^D
morte: 
Context:
Nat : *

Expression: (λ(Zero : Nat) → Zero) (λ(a : *) → λ(Succ : a → a) → λ(Zero : a) → Zero)

Error: Function applied to argument of the wrong type

Expected type: Nat
Argument type: ∀(a : *) → ∀(Succ : a → a) → ∀(Zero : a) → a
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You simply misplaced a parentheses. Swap the 4th line and the 5 the line, and type check passes.